# math.fmod always euqls math.mod?

Tags: lua

I tried to figure out the difference between math.fmod and math.mod with the following code:

```
a={9.5 ,-9.5,-9.5,9.5}
b={-3.5, 3.5,-3.5,3.5}
for i=1,#a do
    if math.fmod(a[i],b[i])~=math.mod(a[i],b[i]) then
        print("yeah")
    end
end
```

It never prints "yeah"!
What should I put in array a and b to see "yeah"?

The documentation of **math.fmod()** say that it returns the remainder of the division of x by y that rounds the quotient towards zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`math.mod` is the *same* function as `math.fmod`. Actually, `math.mod` exists only for compatibility with previous versions; it's not listed in the manual. Try `math.modf` instead of `math.mod` in your code.

Comment: but modf is a totally different function from fmod. according to documentation: math.modf (x) Returns two numbers, the integral part of x and the fractional part of x. but math.fmod (x, y) Returns the remainder of the division of x by y that rounds the quotient towards zero.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo in Lua is defined as "the remainder of a division that rounds the quotient towards minus infinity" -[Link here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.1) - Which is different from the definition of fmod (as you quoted in your original post).

What you really need to do is use the modulo operator (%) rather than math.mod:

```
a={9.5 ,-9.5,-9.5,9.5}
b={-3.5, 3.5,-3.5,3.5}
for i=1,#a do
    if math.fmod(a[i],b[i]) ~= a[i] % b[i] then
        print("yeah")
    end
end
```